# DjangoCMS toolbar missing

Tags: python, css, django, django-cms, django-sekizai

DjangoCMS Toolbar not appearing in Firefox (and Epiphany). It shows up OK in Chrome though.

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% render_block "css" %}
    </head>
    <body>
      {% cms_toolbar %}
      {% placeholder base_product %}
      {% block base_product %}
      {% endblock %}
      <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
    {% render_block "js" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Have already asked about it on django-cms project on [GitHub](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/2101) and waiting for response.

In Chrome the header looks like below:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/cms/css/plugins/cms.toolbar.css?v1" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/cms/css/plugins/cms.placeholders.css?v1" media="all" />    
</head>
```

In Firefox the header does not contain any links to css django-cms specific resources and as a result, I believe, the toolbar is missing in the body.

```
<head>
</head>
```

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: @Hieu Nguyen, Cheers got it sorted by myself. I was expecting the toolbar to show up before getting authenticated which turned out to be a wrong assumption

Comment: Nice that you figured it out. Maybe remove the question or post an answer yourself then :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toolbar shows up as expected after getting authenticated through admin panel first